# I get AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' when using pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im working in Jupyter and all of a sudden pandas won´t create a dataframe for me. The name of the notebook is "Cálculo_Energía_gases", I don´t think there is a name conflict.

This is the code:

```
df_energía_gases = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Presión (Pa)","rpm","Q (m3/s)","MWgases (MW)","ref_prod","m3_prod"])
```

Pandas won´t work in other Jupiter notebooks, but it does work in visualstudiocode. I don´t know what is happening. What can I try to solve it?

Comment: Can you show where you've imported pandas please

Comment: In the cell just above this one.

Comment: import pandas as pd

Comment: Welcome to SO Sam, please include all of the relevant code. So including your import, and the whole error.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a file called `pandas.py` in the same directory. When you import a module python will first search the directory you are in and then will check your python path for other modules. Delete or rename the `pandas.py` and everything should work.

Comment: I can´t find any file called pandas.py in my directory.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you spelled it DataFrame with capital D and F.